# Java: Returning InOrder Traversal as String to JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, binary-tree

Trying to return the output of an InOrder traversal to a Java JLabel. I am able to return the contents of an ArrayList but need the output to be a String without the [,,,]. I'm sure its a simple solution but I have been stuck for a while trying different things, basically chasing my tail. Any help provided is much appreciated.

GUI portion:
Stores input from textfield as String originalList. Attempts to set the text of the JLabel "resultBox" with output from getResult().

```
        if (e.getSource() == sortBtn) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            String originalList = readN();
            resultBox.setText(getResult(originalList));
            System.out.println("Original List: " + originalList);
        }
```

getResult() tokenizes the originalList and inserts into BinarySearchTree 'tree' and returns the inorder traversal 'tree.inOrder()'

```
   public static String getResult(String tokenString) {

        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(tokenString, "()*/+- ", false);

        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String tkn = tokens.nextToken();

            if(tkn.equals(" ")) {
                //ignore spaces
            }
            else {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(tkn);
                tree.insert(key);
            }
        }
        return tree.inorder();
    }
```

inorder() calls inorderRec() and returns result.

```
// This method mainly calls inorderRec() 
    String inorder()  { 
       String result = inorderRec(root);
       return result;
    } 

    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
    String inorderRec(Node root) {

        if (root != null) { 
            inorderRec(root.left); 
            keyList.add(root.key);
            inorderRec(root.right);
        }
        return String.valueOf(keyList);
        //return result;
    }
```

If using input 50 30 20 40 70 60 80 result seen for JLabel should be 20 30 40 50 60 70 80, but actual output is [20, 30, 40, 50, 60 ,70 ,80]

Comment: both output are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.valueOf(keyList)` calls the `toString` of the list - thus you are ending up with the representation.

Rather, construct the output in the desired format after the `inorderRec` method returns. For this, I see there is no need to return anything from `inorderRec` as you are adding to *some* list (`keyList`) (that you haven't shown where it is being created)

```
String inorder()  { 
   inorderRec(root);
   return String.join(" ", ketList);
} 

void inorderRec(Node root) {

    if (root != null) { 
        inorderRec(root.left); 
        keyList.add(root.key);
        inorderRec(root.right);
    }
}
```

`String.join`'s javadoc states

> Returns a new {@code String} composed of copies of the {@code CharSequence elements} joined together with a copy of the specified {@code delimiter}.

Comment: Sorry about that keyList was outside of the scope but was initially inside inorderRec(). Was trying all kinds of combinations and never put it back. String.join did not work either. You did help me with letting me know I did not need both returns, appreciate that.

Comment: Do update your question with your current code so that we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8 or above, you could use the `String.join()` API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to join all the elements of the list into a single String with a given delimiter. For example:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Mark", "Stacy", "Gretta");
System.out.println(String.join(" ", names));
```

would output:

`Mark Stacy Gretta`

Comment: I attempted to use String.join but output console barked up a lot of red errors :(

Comment: Could you upload those errors? That’ll help figure out what’s amiss

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I thin user7 gave me a clue with "construct the output in the desired format after the inorderRec method returns." I had initially iterated keyList in inorderRec() but would only output one index, most likely because the statement in the loop was:

result = String.valueOf(keyList.get(i) + " ");

instead of

result += String.valueOf(keyList.get(i) + " ");

I moved that up to inorder() and everything outputs correctly. Thanks a lot to both of you for the help. Much appreciated!

Updated code outputs correctly:

```
// This method mainly calls InorderRec() 
    String inorder()  { 
       //String result = inorderRec(root);
       inorderRec(root);
       for (int i = 0; i < keyList.size(); i++) {
                //System.out.print(keyList.get(i) + " ");
                result += String.valueOf(keyList.get(i) + " ");
            }
       return result;
    } 

    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
    void inorderRec(Node root) {

        if (root != null) { 
            inorderRec(root.left); 
            keyList.add(root.key);
            inorderRec(root.right);
        }
    }
```

[GUI output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYG5O.png)